# The sql code I wrote outputs three lines instead of one due to nulls in the other fields, how can i amend to put all the data in a one line output?

Tags: sql

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izG5m.png)

I am guessing due to the nulls being present, the code pulls each row as a separate row from the source table, but the data is all about one trip id, how can I amend this so that i get all three rows condensed into one.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try to add the code in your question and avoid using images. Please see the ways to post a question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    SELECT
       TOUR_ROUTE_ID
    ,  SUM( [Country 1]) AS [Country 1]
    ,  SUM( [Country 2]) AS [Country 2]
    ,  SUM( [Country 3]) AS [Country 3] 
FROM 
(
SELECT TRC.TOUR_ROUTE_ID
,  CASE WHEN TRC.SEQUENCE = 1 THEN MAX(TRC.COUNTRY_ID) END AS [Country 1]
,  CASE WHEN TRC.SEQUENCE = 2 THEN MAX(TRC.COUNTRY_ID) END AS [Country 2]
,  CASE WHEN TRC.SEQUENCE = 3 THEN MAX(TRC.COUNTRY_ID) END AS [Country 3] 
FROM IMTMS_TOUR_ROUTE_COUNTRY as TRC 
WHERE TRC.TOUR_ROUTE_ID = 4985 
GROUP BY TRC.TOUR_ROUTE_ID, TRC.SEQUENCE 
)A
GROUP BY TOUR_ROUTE_ID;
```

Comment: Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: i got this error messgae

Comment: My bad, didn't noticed the MAX. Edited. Please try this one

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, just use aggregation (sum) for the case statements in the select list. Then group it by route id

Comment: USE IMTMS_INBOUND_REP
GO

SELECT
TRC.TOUR_ROUTE_ID,
[Country 1] = CASE
       WHEN TRC.SEQUENCE = 1
             THEN MAX(TRC.COUNTRY_ID)
             END,
[Country 2] = CASE
       WHEN TRC.SEQUENCE = 2
             THEN MAX(TRC.COUNTRY_ID)
             END,
[Country 3] = CASE
       WHEN TRC.SEQUENCE = 3
             THEN MAX(TRC.COUNTRY_ID)
             END
FROM IMTMS_TOUR_ROUTE_COUNTRY as TRC
WHERE TRC.TOUR_ROUTE_ID = 4985
GROUP BY TRC.TOUR_ROUTE_ID,
TRC.SEQUENCE

Comment: can you please show me an example code of how to do this?